# How can we test performance of a mobile application(both android and IOS)

Tags: performance, mobile, android, ios

I need to test the performance of a mobile application.
I have used Jmeter tool to test it's services and APIs, but we want to test it's performance in device as well. is there any tool using which we can test the performance of a mobile application.

A single open source tool which can help with both applications i.e. android and IOS is preferred.

If there is any another way, with which we can test the performance of a application is also welcome.

Comment: please define "performance" first

Comment: To determine how a application performs in terms of responsiveness and stability under a particular workload. Since it's a mobile app i have tested  its services for user load and i want to check the responsiveness and stability in mobile for single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no single tool which will allow you to do it on both platforms so I would suggest the following combination:

1. Android: [Performance Profiling Tools](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html)
2. iOS: [Performance Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/PerformanceOverview/PerformanceTools/PerformanceTools.html)
3. Simulate lots of mobile users (load testing the backend): almost any tool from [this list](http://www.opensourcetesting.org/category/testing-tools-overview/performance/?menu-page=overview), for example [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which can even [record mobile applicaiton traffic](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy).

Answer (score 0):

Try https://rungutan.com/

They have an article posted on how to do it -> https://medium.com/@marius.mitrofan/load-test-a-mobile-app-api-with-rungutan-efd66dc194f4